# Calculate running totals for multiple dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

Please see bottom of question for test data..

I have data like below..

```
salesorder  datee
1          2016-11-10
1          2016-11-10
2          2016-11-09
2          2016-11-09
```

Now i want to display my data like below

```
datee       Summ
2016-11-09  4
2016-11-10  6
```

So i have used below query ,which gives me the exact result

```
select distinct 
datee,
sum(salesorder) over (order by datee)
from
#test
```

But the issue with above query is,it uses Range option and uses Disk spool(if work table has records ,then it is Disk based spool) ,and not  in memory spool..You can verify the same using below

```
set statistics io on
select distinct 
datee,
sum(salesorder) over (order by datee)
from
#test
```

> **Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 3, logical reads 21,** physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table '#test_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________00000001A8B8'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

One way to get InMemory spool is to use Rows option like below

```
select 
datee,
sum(salesorder) over ( order by datee rows between  unbounded preceding and  current row )
from
#test
```

The above query uses an InMemory spool and is very fast,but the output is not what i want..below is the output

```
datee       summ
2016-11-09  2
2016-11-09  4
2016-11-10  5
2016-11-10  6
```

InMemoryspool is very fast compared to Disk spool.this is documented here:[Microsoft SQL Server 2012 High-Performance T-SQL Using Window Functions (Developer Reference)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735658366)

So my question is :
How can i use InMemory Spool and get the result i want.I tried with Various framing options,but i am not getting desired result

**Test data:**

```
create table #test
(
salesorder int,
datee date
)
go

insert into #test
select 1,getdate()-1
go 2


insert into #test
select 2,getdate()-2
go 2
```

**Note :**
Rows option will work ,if i don't have duplicate dates,but my data set up is like that and i have thousands of records like the sample

**Update:**
this is part of a large query ,so i prefer  window functions (with out CTE or derived tables) to avoid rewriting

Comment: have you tried selecting distinct date the CROSS APPLY to the SUM OF salesorder  ?

Comment: I think,even if i use cross apply with distinct dates,i won't be getting cumulative sum ,further this is part of  a large query ,so i prefer window functions to avoid rewriting

Comment: If you put a derived table in a CTE, wont you avoid the rewriting?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza:integrating this to main query is very hard with CTE approach,i have shown you the summary of the problem,if i go with approach of cte,i have to join this twice..I have updated the question now.sorry for not updating earlier

Comment: @TheGameiswar just wondered what actual performance you were seeing from your query which works but uses disk spool.

Comment: @SteveFord:  the performance is worse,as i have year long data starting from 2016 and we calculate MTD,YTD as well

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct T1.dattee,X.Summ from SalesTab T1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(T2.SalesOrder) SUMM FROM SalesTab T2 WHERE T2.dattee<=T1.dattee) X
    ORDER BY T1.Dattee
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using this:

```
SELECT  datee, 
        sum(salesorder) over 
            ( order by datee rows between  unbounded preceding and  current row )
FROM (
      SELECT datee,
             sum(salesorder) as salesorder
      from #test
      GROUP BY datee
     ) t
```

This gives the following:

> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0. Table
>   '#test_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________0000000000A3'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
>   lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Edit:

> If you don't want to use this technique, then try a variation of
>   your own query wrapping it with Row_NUMBER(), still uses IN Memeory:
>
> ```
> SELECT datee, salesorder
> FROM (
>       SELECT datee, salesorder, 
>              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY datee ORDER BY salesorder DESC) AS RN
>       FROM (
>               SELECT  datee,
>                       sum(salesorder) over ( order by datee rows between  unbounded preceding and  current row ) As salesorder
>               FROM #test
>           ) t1
>   ) t2
> WHERE RN = 1
> ```

Comment: I have this solution,but i don't want to access this way due to many reasons .Thanks

Comment: @TheGameiswar Maybe you can elaborate why not, so other doesnt give similar answers?